# I want my youtube videos to always play from the beginning, not where it left off last time

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

When I load a youtube video into my web page, I want it to default to playing from the beginning. I'm using javascript code to control it and I need it to start there initially. Every time I reload the page, though, the video plays where it left off and I can't test my script.

Comment: can you add "?t=0s" to the video URL? I do something like this when I want a video to start at say 30s from the beginning.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. just didn't know what to try. that might be a good idea, though. I'll give it a whirl. thanks.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. still picks up where it last left off when I set    videoId: 'UG8DX3LxDb8?t=0s',  in onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()

Comment: I have also tried setting player.seekTo(0.00);  and it will initially cue up there, but when I hit play it will again jump to the last viewed position.

Comment: also tried player.seeTo(0) on page load (with no milliseconds) with no luck. you'd think there'd be a way of overriding the last played position via javascript.

Comment: (1) Use @ to notify a specific person (otherwise they won't know you've replied them)... (2) Make a basic test page so we can check issue in action and check the used code for any problems. Else [**edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46227813/edit) to show your code. Instead of guesses, you'll get a faster answer if your issue can be re-created or analysed.

Comment: Have you tried calling `stopVideo()` on it? That should reset it back to the beginning.

Comment: I don't think stopVideo() is what i need to use. According to the documentation: stopVideo() stops and cancels loading of the current video. This function should be reserved for rare situations when you know that the user will not be watching additional video in the player. If your intent is to pause the video, you should just call the pauseVideo function.

Answer (score 1):

Following the API's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) this should  work:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  // The IFrame Player API code should be added here

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      videoId: 'UG8DX3LxDb8',
      playerVars: {
         'start': 0
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }
</script>
```

This code generates an iframe showing the video with id 'UG8DX3LxDb8' and the playerVar `start` tells the API to start at 0 seconds.

Comment: Please write what you expect to see and what you tried to do to fix it